# Leaflet Basemap zoom to maximum

Tags: leaflet, zoom

When I zoom to maximum; more than 18 the basemap is gone.

How can we keep the basemap even when we zoom to maximum?

This is my [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GD5m6QIYsLy7v4tI3AJ4?p=preview)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Tile Layer [`maxZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-maxzoom) option default value is `18`.

> The maximum zoom level up to which this layer will be displayed (inclusive).

That is why it is automatically hidden when you zoom past level 18.

To keep it visible, simply specify that option when instantiating the Tile Layer:

```js
var OSMRoads = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 22,
  maxNativeZoom: 19
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Note that in the case of OpenStreetMap, the Tile Server does not send images for zoom level higher than 19. But you can use the [`maxNativeZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer-maxnativezoom) option to have Leaflet keep images from the last available zoom level and scale them up:

> Maximum zoom number the tile source has available. If it is specified, the tiles on all zoom levels higher than `maxNativeZoom` will be loaded from `maxNativeZoom` level and auto-scaled.

Updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/1zgrFv504ywvbuo2QHLe?p=preview